# Querying a nested document in PyMongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I want to print a list of all the first names, and the year the prize was won of all the entries in this database called NobelDB, collection name, laureate.

I can print the first names with the following code in PyMongo:

```
Q = laureate.find({})
for q in Q:
    print(q['firstname'])
```

However, when I add a nested query into the for loop as below, it prints an error:

```
Q = laureate.find({})
for q in Q:
print(q['firstname'],
     q['prizes.year'])
```

How do I amend the code so it will print all of the first names, and the year they won the prize which is located within the 'prizes' document.

The data collection is split into two nested documents at 'prizes' and then again at 'affiliations' as below:

```
{'_id': ObjectId('60534c9fe877bf1b14149668'), 'id': '2', 'firstname': 'Hendrik A.', 'surname': 'Lorentz', 'born': '1853-07-18', 'died': '1928-02-04', 'bornCountry': 'the Netherlands', 'bornCountryCode': 'NL', 'bornCity': 'Arnhem', 'diedCountry': 'the Netherlands', 'diedCountryCode': 'NL', 'gender': 'male', 
'prizes': [{'year': '1902', 'category': 'physics', 'share': '2', 'motivation': '"in recognition of the extraordinary service they rendered by their researches into the influence of magnetism upon radiation phenomena"', 
'affiliations': [{'name': 'Leiden University', 'city': 'Leiden', 'country': 'the Netherlands'}]}]}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `prizes` is a list, you can access its elements with the index.

```
q["prizes"][0]["year"]
```

And if you want to print all the years, you will have to do an other loop

```
for q in Q:
    print(q['firstname'])
    for prize in q["prizes"]
        print(prize["year")
```

Comment: You're welcome. you can mark the answer as accepted to "close" the question